# multidimensional array sorting by column in java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

i need some help in this problem, there are three columns namely phase#, block# and lot#, i needed to sort the phase# in ascending order while the other two will be sorted accordingly to its phase#:

Problem:

Phase#   1-2-1-3-1-2-1

Block#   1-1-2-1-2-1-1

Lot#     1-2-2-2-3-1-1

What it should be like:

Phase#   1-1-1-1-2-2-3

Block#   1-2-2-1-1-1-1

Lot#     1-2-3-1-2-1-2

here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int x = 7;
    int y = 3;
    int[][] phase= new int[x][y];
    int swap = 0, temp, i, min = 0;

     phase[0][0] = 1;
     phase[1][0] = 2;
     phase[2][0] = 1;
     phase[3][0] = 3;
     phase[4][0] = 1;
     phase[5][0] = 2;
     phase[6][0] = 1;
     phase[0][1] = 1;
     phase[1][1] = 1;
     phase[2][1] = 2;
     phase[3][1] = 1;
     phase[4][1] = 2;
     phase[5][1] = 1;
     phase[6][1] = 1;
     phase[0][2] = 2;
     phase[1][2] = 2;
     phase[2][2] = 2;
     phase[3][2] = 2;
     phase[4][2] = 3;
     phase[5][2] = 1;
     phase[6][2] = 1;

    System.out.println("UNSORTED: \n");
    System.out.println("Phase#\tBlock#\tLot#"); 
     for(i = 0; i < phase.length; i++){
        System.out.print(phase[i][0] + "\t" + phase[i][1] + "\t"+phase[i][2]);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("\nSORTED:\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= phase.length- 1; i++){
        min = i;
        for(int a = i+1; a < phase.length; a++ ){
            if(phase[a][0]<phase[a][0]){
                temp=phase[i][0];
                phase[i][0]=phase[a][0];
                phase[a][0]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Phase#\tBlock#\tLot#"); 
     for(int j = 0; j < phase.length; j++){
        System.out.print(phase[j][0] + "\t" + phase[j][1] + "\t"+phase[j][2]);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparator interface as (int [] left, int[] right) -> left[0]-right[0] and pass it to Arrays.sort() method:

```
Arrays.sort(phase, (int [] left, int[] right) -> left[0]-right[0]);
```